# AntDesign Cascader: error Not found value in options

Tags: reactjs, redux, components, antd

I am wanting to use the "Cascader" component of "Ant Design" but I am having trouble filling it with data. This is my code, which I am doing wrong, sorry I am still a newbie and I need your support please.

```
function CascaderEmpCliUn(props) {
    const optionLists = { a: []}
    const [state, setState] = useState(optionLists);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function asyncFunction(){
            const empresas = await props.loginReducer.data.empresas;
            const options = [
                empresas.map(empresa => ({
                    value: empresa.id,
                    label: empresa.siglas,
                    children: [
                        empresa.cli_perm.map(cliente => ({
                            value: cliente.id,
                            label: cliente.siglas,
                            children: [
                                cliente.uunn_perm.map(un => ({
                                    value: un.id,
                                    label: un.nombre,
                                }))
                            ]
                        }))
                    ]})
                )
            ];
            setState({a : options})
        }
        asyncFunction();
    }, [])

    return (
        <Cascader options={state.a} placeholder="Please select" />
    )
}
```

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ojLs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Not found `value` in `options`

I was able to reproduce your error with dummy data whenever I had an empty array of `children` at any level.  I'm not sure why this should be a problem, but it is.  So you need to modify your mapping function to check the length of the child arrays.  It seems to be fine if passing `undefined` instead of an empty array if there are no children.

#### General Suggestions

You don't need to store the options in component state when you are getting them from redux.  It can just be a derived variable.  You can use `useMemo` to prevent unnecessary recalculation.

You are passing the entire `loginReducer` state in your props which is not ideal because it could cause useless re-renders if values change that you aren't actually using.  So you want to minimize the amount of data that you select from redux.  Just select the `empresas`.

#### Revised Code

```
function CascaderEmpCliUn() {
    // you could do this with connect instead
    const empresas = useSelector(
        (state) => state.loginReducer.data?.empresas || []
    );

    // mapping the data to options
    const options = React.useMemo(() => {
        return empresas.map((empresa) => ({
            value: empresa.id,
            label: empresa.siglas,
            children:
                empresa.cli_perm.length === 0
                    ? undefined
                    : empresa.cli_perm.map((cliente) => ({
                        value: cliente.id,
                        label: cliente.siglas,
                        children:
                            cliente.uunn_perm.length === 0
                                ? undefined
                                : cliente.uunn_perm.map((un) => ({
                                    value: un.id,
                                    label: un.nombre
                                }))
                    }))
        }));
    }, [empresas]);

    return <Cascader options={options} placeholder="Please select" />;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your code compiles correctly, except for a small correction in the object "options", some unnecessary brackets that I put in the first and second children, the novelty for me is that "map" does not need us to put brackets to create arrays.

Comment: @JoséGuzmán I should have noticed that!  Yes you don't need brackets because `.map` already returns an `array`.

Answer (score 0):

The final code of "options" object:

```
const options = useMemo(() => {
        return empresas.map((empresa) => ({
            value: empresa.id,
            label: empresa.siglas,
            children:
                empresa.cli_perm.length === 0
                    ? console.log("undefined")
                    :
                        empresa.cli_perm.map((cliente) => ({
                            value: cliente.id,
                            label: cliente.siglas,
                            children:
                                cliente.uunn_perm.length === 0
                                    ? console.log("undefined")
                                    :
                                        cliente.uunn_perm.map((un) => ({
                                            value: un.id,
                                            label: un.nombre
                                        }))

                        }))

        }));
    }, [empresas]);
```